# iMessage went from showing what time it was read to just delivered?

Tags: messages

I sent an iMessage and it showed it was read at 18.01. Few hours later it just says delivered and the message i sent before the last one shows the time it was read. Why did it go from read at 18.01 to just delivered? Have i been blocked by this person or what?

Comment: Not sure which version of iOS you operate on but if it's on a public beta there are quite some complaints on Apple Discussions about not showing the read receipt all of a sudden

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this too on my own device. It is a bug, though it has persisted through several iOS 9 releases. (I think it started with 9.3 but I'm not positive on that.) It does not affect read receipt display on Messages for Mac.

Read receipts are not retroactive, so even if you were blocked or the other person changed their read receipt setting, this would not occur. If you watch, when a future message is received, you will likely see that the last read receipt shown will move forward one message, to the message immediately before the latest message (in other words, the one where it is not displaying right now).

You can use the [iPhone feedback tool](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) to report this bug to Apple.

Answer (score -2):

If you -or your recipient- go to Settings > Messages you can disable "Send Read Receipts" which will have the effect described to the other party using iMessage.
[image: settings - messages "send read receipt"]

From [an article](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/can-i-turn-off-message-read-receipts-for-only-some-users) on the subject:

> however it’s also important to note that this setting only applies to the current device. If you’re using iMessage across multiple devices — such as on a Mac and/or iPad — you’ll need to turn the setting OFF individually on each of your devices if you don’t want read receipts sent from those devices. Note that users will still see that messages have been “Delivered” — there’s no way to turn this one off

Comment: This does not address the question, because read receipt settings do not apply retroactively. Meaning, if you have read receipts turn off and you turn them on, the other party will only see read receipts for messages they send after that time. If you have them turned on and you turn them off, the last read receipt shown will be the last message they sent before you turned it off. In other words, it wouldn't go from showing the time on the last message to showing the time on the message before that, regardless of read receipt settings.

Comment: Excellent point, my bad. It may be that the recipient has more than one device and it's the "Send Read Receipts" it's turned on on other of their devices? I'll try to reproduce the scenario.

Comment: That still wouldn't explain it though - once you've read a message, it's read, regardless of where. All other devices containing that message then silently mark that message as read, without user interaction on those devices. The settings on the device actively being used would determine whether a read receipt is sent, and the settings on the rest wouldn't matter because the recipient didn't "read" the message on those devices. See my answer. I'm positive this is a bug. It happens to every contact I have that uses iMessage and I know for a fact some of them only have one iMessage device.

Comment: Ok, I'll probably delete the answer once it gets enough downvotes. Thanks for the clarification.